# Testing StoreKit auto-renewing subscriptions locally, expiration date is always nil

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, storekit, auto-renewing

I am trying to test auto-renewing subscriptions in my iOS app locally with StoreKit using Xcode 13.1 by the way of local receipt validation. I am using a StoreKit configuration file to test the subscriptions.

I do the auto-renewing subscription purchase in the simulator and my code can validate the receipt and finds the purchased product identifier, however, the Subscription Expiration Date is always nil in the purchase record found in the receipt. Therefore, I can't see if it is a valid subscription or not.

Anyone have any idea about this?